# How many failed audits does it take to ban a user from review?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I have passed almost 7 audits while reviewing *Close Votes*, *Suggested Edits*, *Low Quality Posts* and *Triage*, but I also failed 2 audits today,

My question is, how are bans calculated with respect to failed audits? How many failed audits do I have left before I am banned from reviewing?